# Radio Button Name Changes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

I created 2 radio buttons

```
<input type="radio" name="ApprovalGroup" runat="server" id="ApprovedOnly" value="true" />Approved
<input type="radio" name="ApprovalGroup" runat="server" id="UnapprovedOnly" value="false" />Unapproved
```

And was able to access them from js with `$("input[name=ApprovalGroup]:checked").val()` But then I needed to add `runat="server"` so I could access the radio button in the code behind.

The problem I have is the radio button name is being changed because of the content place holder. I'm using `ClientIDMode="Static"` but it only protects the id value, not the name. The radio button is rendered as

```
<input value="true" name="ctl00$cphContent$ApprovalGroup" type="radio" id="ApprovedOnly" />Approved
<input value="false" name="ctl00$cphContent$ApprovalGroup" type="radio" id="UnapprovedOnly" />Unapproved
```

Is it possible to prevent the name from changing?

Comment: I think all 3 answers were good and didn't know which to mark as the answer, so I marked the one that I ended up using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `$=` selector, which selects attributes whose values end with the given substring:

```
$("input[name$=ApprovalGroup]:checked")
```

Comment: So why not just use the "ends with" selector since the original name will always be at the end of the generated name (per ASP.NET's convention)? Safer, where `*=` could match "ApprovalGroupSecond". And probably saves a little processing that we don't see, but still.

Comment: `$=` would be the way to go here. `*=` would cause issues if you also had a control named `ApprovalGroupValidator`, for instance. ASP only prepends.

Comment: @Ian ah so you did! Must have happened whilst I was typing :P

Comment: @JamesDonnelly It was just funny to me :)

Answer (score 3):

.NET wants the name for its own purposes, but that doesn't stop you for using a CSS class name for your own.

That way you can use `$('.classname').val()`. You can use individual class names for fields, or share them to make groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("input[name*=ApprovalGroup]:checked")
```

is a good solution but if there is another input that contains these words, then it can be occured a conflict. So safer solution is to use your own attribute.
such as;

```
 <input type="radio" name="ApprovalGroup" data-group="group1" runat="server" id="ApprovedOnly" value="true" />Approved
 <input type="radio" name="ApprovalGroup" data-group="group1" runat="server" id="UnapprovedOnly" value="false" />Unapproved
```

then use filter below;

```
$("input[data-group='group1']:checked")
```

Comment: If you're going to suggest using a custom attribute, at least suggest a valid one - http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/